# Passing angularjs data to bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

First of all, I'm pretty new to angularjs.. So when I'm trying to pass data from angularjs controller to a bootstrap modal they don't don't display.

**Trigger**

```
<a ng-click="editarEndereco(item)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalLong">Editar</a>
```

**Modal**

```
<div  class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document" >
        <div class="modal-content" ng-controller="listaEnderecosController">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">Alterar informações deste endereço</h4>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            {{enderecoAlterar.bairro}} 
            <div class="modal-body" >

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS Controller**

```
$scope.enderecoAlterar = {};

$scope.editarEndereco = function (item) {
    $scope.enderecoAlterar = item;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

From this implementation you will not be able to pass parameters to the modal.

First you should seperate `id="exampleModalLong"` div with inside content to a new html file.

Then edit this `<a>` tag as below,

```
<a ng-click="editarEndereco(item)" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs">Editar</a>
```

And inside your controller, edit `editarEndereco` function as below,

```
$scope.editarEndereco = function (item) {

    var modalInstance = $modal.open({
    controller: 'CREATE A NEW CONTROLLER FOR THE MODAL AS WELL. IF YOU ALREADY HAVE IT. MENTION IT HERE',
    templateUrl: 'YOUR NEWLY CREATED HTML FILE URL HERE',
    resolve: {
      enderecoAlterar : item
    }
  });

};
```

Then inside the `modalinstance` controller inject `enderecoAlterar` & use it

Comment: `$modal` is not available unless you use `angular-ui-bootstrap`. So you either show the OP how to show a modal without using `angular-ui-boostrap` or redirect the OP to `angular-ui-bootstrap`.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing it using the **angular.copy(item, $scope.item);** function.
This is how I have done it in my code:

```js
$scope.confirmDelete = function (item) {
        $scope.item = {};
        angular.copy(item, $scope.item);
        $('#delete-item-modal').modal({
            show: true
        });
    }
```

```html
<a role="button" ng-click="confirmDelete(offer)">Delete</a>
 
 
 
 <!-- Confirm delete modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="delete-item-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
     <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Delete element</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-16">
            Are you sure you want to delete <strong>{{item.offerTitle}}</strong>?
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      <form novalidate name="deleteOfferForm" ng-submit="deleteOffer(item)">
            <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="{{appData.securityTokenName}}" value="{{appData.securityToken}}">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-xs btn-danger">Delete</button>
            </form>
         
      </div>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code snippet obviously doesn't work here... but you get the point.